# Why is this true by Markov's Inequality?

Tags: probability

In the beginning of page 7 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11882.pdf) I'm reading, it says that the mass that $P_n$ assigns to each $B_j$ is at most $Le^{-2^{2j-3}}$ by Markov's inequality, but I don't understand how Markov's inequality implies that.

I usually think of Markov's inequality as $P(X>a) <= EX/a$ but how does that tell us anything about the most mass assigned to $B_j$? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Why was this downvoted.

Comment: I have no idea; I just upvoted it to compensate for it. I don't think you need to "show work" for a question on a paper. Will have a look at your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Markov's inequality is a very general inequality, and this is an application of it. (You might hear this one as Chernoff, though this is a special case of that too in that it is applied to empirical distributions.) While reading this paper, do note that $P_n$ is a probability distribution that puts a mass of $1/n$ on each $x_i$, so we can talk about probabilities and expectations under it. In particular, in their notation,

$$L = E_{P_n} e^{\frac{|X|^2}{2 d \sigma^2}} $$

where we have $X$ a random sample chosen by $P_n$. Now:

\begin{align*}
P_{P_n}(X \in B_j) &\leq P_{P_n}(|X|^2 \geq d(2^{2(j-1)} \sigma^2)) \\
&=P_{P_n}(e^{\frac{|X|^2}{2 \sigma^2 d}} \geq e^{2^{2j - 3}}) \\
&\leq Le^{-2^{2j - 3}}    
\end{align*}

where the last inequality is Markov's inequality indeed.

Comment: Why is the first inequality $\leq$ instead of $\geq$? Should it be reversed? If $X\not\in B_j$, then $\left\|X\right\|^2 \geq d(2^{2j}\sigma^2)$ OR it's $\leq d(2^{2j-2}\sigma^2)$, no?

Comment: I completely tripped myself up... The bound is for controlling the amount of mass on $B_j$, and now hopefully the implication goes the right way!

Comment: (and the -3 now makes sense too; it matches the paper; that should have clued me that I was wrong and it wasn't a typo in the paper...)  Good catch!

Comment: Thank you so much!